# Running OpenNI example in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, openni

I was trying to run OpenCV example to grab OpenNI video from kinect sensor.
I have installed OpenNI by:
sudo apt-get install libopenni-dev libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev

and compiled OpenCV from latest source from Github enabling -DWITH_OPENNI=ON.

But when I run ./cpp-example-openni_capture it shows following error:

Device opening ... 
CvCapture_OpenNI::CvCapture_OpenNI : Failed to run xml script: Bad Parameter sent to the device!
done. 
Can not open a capture object.

Can anyone please tell why am I having this error? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.